I accidentally deleted Notes from iCloud
While attempting to clean an iPad to give away I accidentally deleted my Notes on iCloud.
I have a backup of my current iPad (although slightly out of date).
I have a current TimeMachine backup on my Mac.
Is there a way I can restore from TimeMachine (or failing that restore iPad).
Cloud Data Recovery offers a number of options; Contacts etc but not Notes.

There’s a Data Recovery feature on iCloud.  Did you try that?

@Allan I was unaware of Data Recovery feature. Do you have any details (I don't want to cause any more damage). I have signed in on iCloud but can't see anything obvious

In iCloud there is a grid of dots (icon for menu I guess).  Click that and you’ll see an option for data recovery. If the files can be recovered you can do so for up to 30 days.

If iCloud recovery does not work, try by restoring '/Users//Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/' from Time Machine.
